# PostgreSQL timeseries query with outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, time-series, outer-join

In PostgreSQL 9.5 database there is a table *metrics_raw* containing various metrics (*types: varchar*).
Types are (for example): *TRA*, *RTC*.
I'm executing following SQL to get year-to-date monthly aggregations:

```
SELECT
  count(*),
  "ticks"."ts" AS "timestamp"
FROM
  "metrics_raw"
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-10-10'::timestamp, '1 month'::interval) AS ticks(ts)
ON
  "ticks"."ts" = date_trunc('months', "metrics_raw"."timestamp")
WHERE
  "metrics_raw"."type" = 'TRA' OR
  "metrics_raw"."type" IS NULL
GROUP BY "ticks"."ts"
ORDER BY "ticks"."ts"
```

The table contains some records of *TRA* type (~10 records) and 1 record of *RTC* type.
Executing the query for *TRA* I get **10** rows result as expected, but for *RTC* query I get only **7** rows. One more thing is that having no *RTC* metrics I get **10** rows too.

Where could be a mistake?

Comment: The problem is the Where condition. You should turn your query with a left outer join and put the metric_raw.type = into the join closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Nemeros, I fixed query to be:

```
SELECT
  "ticks"."ts" AS "timestamp"
FROM
  generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-10-10'::timestamp, '1 month'::interval) AS ticks(ts)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM "metrics_raw"
    WHERE "metrics_raw"."type" = 'TRA'
  ) as "metrics"
ON
  "ticks"."ts" = date_trunc('months', "metrics"."timestamp")
GROUP BY "ticks"."ts"
ORDER BY "ticks"."ts"
```